# Typescript: adding only an optional property removes type checking

Tags: typescript

I'm using typescript 1.4.1 and have the following code:

```
var hello: {message: string};
hello = {world: 't'};
```

As intended, the typescript compiler outputs an error:

> Type '{ world: string; }' is not assignable to type '{ message:
>   string;     }'. Property 'message' is missing in type '{ world:
>   string; }'. (var) hello: { message: string; }

But if the type contains only an optional property such as in:

```
var hello: {message?: string};
hello = {world: 't'};
```

Then the compiler is perfectly happy, but I would like the error to be detected.

What am'I doing wrong? or is it a typescript bug?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Then the compiler is perfectly happy, but I would the error to be detected.
>   What am'I doing wrong? or is it a typescript bug?

No this is by design. *extra information* is okay as long as the *required information* (in this case nothing) is present.

Comment: OK thanks, indeed! But I think this is very misleading when you have an interface full of optional properties (say HighChartsOptions for instance) and you make a typo. Typescript compiler does nothing for you in this case.

Comment: Here is a bit more about "why" : http://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html