# Safe typing of Object.assign

Tags: typescript

We're looking for a type safe way of using Object.assign. However, we can't seem to make it work.

To show our problem I'll use the copyFields method from the [Generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) documentation

```
function copyFields<T extends U, U>(target: T, source: U): T {
    for (let id in source) {
        target[id] = source[id];
    }
    return target;
}

function makesrc(): Source { return {b: 1, c: "a"}}

interface Source {
    a?: "a"|"b",
    b: number,
    c: "a" | "b"
}
```

I want the engine to prevent me from creating undeclared properties

```
/*1*/copyFields(makesrc(), {d: "d"}); //gives an error
/*2*/copyFields(makesrc(), {a: "d"}); //gives an error
/*3*/copyFields(makesrc(), {c: "d"}); //should give an error, but doesn't because "a"|"b" is a valid subtype of string.

//I don't want to specify all the source properties 
/*4*/copyFields(makesrc(), {b: 2}); //will not give me an error
/*5*/copyFields(makesrc(), {a: "b"}); //should not give an error, but does because string? is not a valid subtype of string
```

We have attempted to solve this with explicitly providing the types to the copyfields call
but we can't find a call that will make all examples work.

For example: 
  to make 5 work you might call copyFields like this:

```
/*5'*/copyFields<Source,{a?:"a"|"b"}>(makesrc(), {a: "b"});
```

but subsequent changes to the Source type (such as removing the "b" option) will now no longer result in a type error

Does anyone know of a way to make this work?

Comment: Take a look at `&` type operator.

Comment: BTW we (Rene is my coworker) found that flow does support this use case https://tryflow.org/?code=ZGVjbGFyZSBpbnRlcmZhY2UgU291cmNlIHsKICAgIGE/OiAiYSIgfCAiYiIsCiAgICBiOiBudW1iZXIsCiAgICBjOiAiYSIgfCAiYiIKfQpmdW5jdGlvbiBtYWtlc3JjKCkgOiBTb3VyY2UgeyByZXR1cm4ge2I6IDEsIGM6ICJhIn19CgovKjEqL09iamVjdC5hc3NpZ24obWFrZXNyYygpLCB7ZDogImQifSk7Ci8qMiovT2JqZWN0LmFzc2lnbihtYWtlc3JjKCksIHthOiAiZCJ9KTsKLyozKi9PYmplY3QuYXNzaWduKG1ha2VzcmMoKSwge2M6ICJkIn0pOwoKLyo0Ki9PYmplY3QuYXNzaWduKG1ha2VzcmMoKSwge2I6IDJ9KTsKLyo1Ki9PYmplY3QuYXNzaWduKG1ha2VzcmMoKSwge2E6ICJiIn0pOw==

Comment: @torazaburo that will not make the required examples fail

Comment: Possibly relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29207118/typescript-adding-only-an-optional-property-removes-type-checking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typescript 2.1.4 to the rescue!

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=interface%20Data%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3F%3A%20%22a%22%7C%22b%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c%3A%20%22a%22%20%7C%20%22b%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20Patch%20%3D%20Partial%3CData%3E%20%0D%0Afunction%20copyFields(target%3A%20Data%2C%20source%3A%20Patch)%3A%20Data%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20id%20in%20source)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20target%5Bid%5D%20%3D%20source%5Bid%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20target%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20makesrc()%3A%20Data%20%7B%20return%20%7Bb%3A%201%2C%20c%3A%20%22a%22%7D%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F*1*%2FcopyFields(makesrc()%2C%20%7Bd%3A%20%22d%22%7D)%3B%20%2F%2Fgives%20an%20error%0D%0A%2F*2*%2FcopyFields(makesrc()%2C%20%7Ba%3A%20%22d%22%7D)%3B%20%2F%2Fgives%20an%20error%0D%0A%2F*3*%2FcopyFields(makesrc()%2C%20%7Bc%3A%20%22d%22%7D)%3B%20%2F%2Fshould%20give%20an%20error%2C%20but%20doesn't%20because%20%22a%22%7C%22b%22%20is%20a%20valid%20subtype%20of%20string.%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2FI%20don't%20want%20to%20specify%20all%20the%20source%20properties%20%0D%0A%2F*4*%2FcopyFields(makesrc()%2C%20%7Bb%3A%202%7D)%3B%20%2F%2Fwill%20not%20give%20me%20an%20error%0D%0A%2F*5*%2FcopyFields(makesrc()%2C%20%7Ba%3A%20%22b%22%7D)%3B%20%2F%2Fshould%20not%20give%20an%20error%2C%20but%20does%20because%20string%3F%20is%20not%20a%20valid%20subtype%20of%20string)

```
interface Data {
    a?: "a"|"b",
    b: number,
    c: "a" | "b"
}

function copyFields<T>(target: T, source: Readonly<Partial<T>>): T {
    for (let id in source) {
        target[id] = source[id];
    }
    return target;
}

function makesrc(): Data { return {b: 1, c: "a"}}

/*1*/copyFields(makesrc(), {d: "d"}); //gives an error
/*2*/copyFields(makesrc(), {a: "d"}); //gives an error
/*3*/copyFields(makesrc(), {c: "d"}); //gives an error

//I don't want to specify all the source properties 
/*4*/copyFields(makesrc(), {b: 2}); //will not give me an error
/*5*/copyFields(makesrc(), {a: "b"}); //will not give me an error
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Object.assign<TargetType, SourceType>(target, source)` - I think it provides type safety.

Comment: If you combine it with Partial, you won't get the IDE complaining about missing required fields.  Eg: `Object.assign<MyType, Partial<MyType>>(myObj, {})`

Answer (score 1):

The best workaround I can think of is to define a second interface (I called it `SourceParts`) that is exactly the same as `Source`, except that all members are optional.

```
function copyFields<T extends U, U>(target: T, source: U): T {
    for (let id in source) {
        target[id] = source[id];
    }
    return target;
}

function makesrc(): Source { return {b: 1, c: "a"}}

interface Source {
    a?: "a"|"b",
    b: number,
    c: "a" | "b"
}

interface SourceParts {
    a?: "a"|"b",
    b?: number,
    c?: "a" | "b"
}

/*1*/copyFields<Source, SourceParts>(makesrc(), {d: "d"}); //gives an error
/*2*/copyFields<Source, SourceParts>(makesrc(), {a: "d"}); //gives an error
/*3*/copyFields<Source, SourceParts>(makesrc(), {c: "d"}); //gives an error

//I don't want to specify all the source properties 
/*4*/copyFields<Source, SourceParts>(makesrc(), {b: 2}); //will not give me an error
/*5*/copyFields<Source, SourceParts>(makesrc(), {a: "b"}); //will not give me an error
```

Here it is on the [Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20copyFields%3CT%20extends%20U%2C%20U%3E(target%3A%20T%2C%20source%3A%20U)%3A%20T%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20for%20(let%20id%20in%20source)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20target%5Bid%5D%20%3D%20source%5Bid%5D%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20return%20target%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Afunction%20makesrc()%3A%20Source%20%7B%20return%20%7Bb%3A%201%2C%20c%3A%20%22a%22%7D%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Source%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3F%3A%20%22a%22%7C%22b%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c%3A%20%22a%22%20%7C%20%22b%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20SourceParts%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20a%3F%3A%20%22a%22%7C%22b%22%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20b%3F%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20c%3F%3A%20%22a%22%20%7C%20%22b%22%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F*1*%2FcopyFields%3CSource%2C%20SourceParts%3E(makesrc()%2C%20%7Bd%3A%20%22d%22%7D)%3B%20%2F%2Fgives%20an%20error%0D%0A%2F*2*%2FcopyFields%3CSource%2C%20SourceParts%3E(makesrc()%2C%20%7Ba%3A%20%22d%22%7D)%3B%20%2F%2Fgives%20an%20error%0D%0A%2F*3*%2FcopyFields%3CSource%2C%20SourceParts%3E(makesrc()%2C%20%7Bc%3A%20%22d%22%7D)%3B%20%2F%2Fgives%20an%20error%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2FI%20don't%20want%20to%20specify%20all%20the%20source%20properties%20%0D%0A%2F*4*%2FcopyFields%3CSource%2C%20SourceParts%3E(makesrc()%2C%20%7Bb%3A%202%7D)%3B%20%2F%2Fwill%20not%20give%20me%20an%20error%0D%0A%2F*5*%2FcopyFields%3CSource%2C%20SourceParts%3E(makesrc()%2C%20%7Ba%3A%20%22b%22%7D)%3B%20%2F%2Fwill%20not%20give%20me%20an%20error%20).

Comment: This solution did occur to us, however for our use case it would take a lot of double templating.

Comment: Yeah, this at least puts the two typedefinitions together so there's a good chance you'll update them both.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this solutions time ago:

```
   /**
     * assign with known properties from target.
     *
     * @param target
     * @param source
     */
    public static safeAssignment(target: any,  source: any) {
        if (isNullOrUndefined(target) || isNullOrUndefined(source)) {
            return;
        }

        for (const att of Object.keys(target)) {
            target[att] = source.hasOwnProperty(att) ? source[att] : target[att];
        }
    }
```

I hope that someone can be useful.
Regards

Answer (score -1):

I have this function:

```
   /**
     * Take every field of fields and put them override them in the complete object
     * NOTE: this API is a bit reverse of extend because of the way generic constraints work in TypeScript
     */
    const updateFields = <T>(fields: T) => <U extends T>(complete: U): U => {
        let result = <U>{};
        for (let id in complete) {
            result[id] = complete[id];
        }
        for (let id in fields) {
            result[id] = fields[id];
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Usage:

```
updateFields({a:456})({a:123,b:123}) // okay
updateFields({a:456})({b:123}) // Error
```

.

## More

I've mentioned this function before in a different context : https://stackoverflow.com/a/32490644/390330

PS: things will get better once JavaScript gets this to stage 3 : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2103

Comment: nice solution, however, our wish is (as mentioned in the comment): "I don't want to specify all the source properties"

Comment: @renevanderark don't have to `updateFields({a:456})({a:123,b:123}) ` only `a` is specified (the source has both `a` and `b`) 

Comment: I'm sorry. That function is really the same as ours, but with currying.  I tried it in the playground (link is too long to paste here) and it fails on the same tests (3 & 5)